# Calculating the proper acceleration of an observer along a scalar field

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I'm trying to go through the derivation of various quantities from this paper by Madsen in 1988 ([here](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/5/4/010/meta), but unfortunately you have to log in), and I've been having some problems replicating the quantities the author found.

The paper considers a scalar field $\phi$ and an observer velocity (which is timelike), given by $u^a = \frac{\partial^a \phi}{\sqrt{-\partial^e \phi \partial_e \phi}}$ (I'm working with the convention that $u^au_a = -1$ and is timelike, unlike the author). Then, the author defines an acceleration, given by $\dot{u}^a = u^b \nabla_b u_a$. I'm having difficulty calculating this quantity.

When I take the covariant derivative, I have to apply the chain rule on $u^a$, correct? If so, I need to calculate a term that looks like $\nabla_b (-\partial^e \phi \partial_e \phi)^{-1/2}$. I'm a bit confused as to how I calculate this. On the one hand, it's a scalar, so this should reduce to a partial derivative. On the other hand, if I break it up with the chain rule, than they become pieces that aren't scalars. I think I'm missing just a small aspect to this calculation, and I'm hoping someone could point this out to me.

For reference, the author lists the solution as:

$$\dot{u}_a = ((-\partial^e \phi \partial_e \phi)^{-2} \left((-\partial^u \phi \partial_u \phi) \partial^b \phi \nabla_b \nabla_a \phi - \partial^b \phi \partial^n \phi \nabla_b \nabla_n \phi  \partial_a \phi \right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a scalar as a product of two tensors
$$
S = V^\mu W_\mu
$$
If we take the covariant derivative of S, we get
\begin{align}
\nabla_\alpha S &= \nabla_\alpha (V^\mu W_\mu) \\
&= (\nabla_\alpha V^\mu) W_\mu + V^\mu (\nabla_\alpha W_\mu) \\
&= (\partial_\alpha V^\mu + \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu} V^\beta) W_\mu + V^\mu (\partial_\alpha W_\mu - \Gamma_{\alpha \mu}^{\beta} W_\beta) \\
&= W_\mu \partial_\alpha V^\mu + \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu} V^\beta W_\mu + V^\mu \partial_\alpha W_\mu - \Gamma_{\alpha \mu}^{\beta} V^\mu W_\beta \\
&= W_\mu \partial_\alpha V^\mu + V^\mu \partial_\alpha W_\mu
\end{align}
as you can see that the second and the last terms are just the same up to dummy indices ($\mu$ and $\beta$). Therefore,
$$
\partial_\alpha (V^\mu W_\mu) = W_\mu \partial_\alpha V^\mu + V^\mu \partial_\alpha W_\mu
$$